# Grails command/domain object propertyName

Tags: grails, gsp

When any validation fails in domain/commandObjects, the error message is taking from message.properties and formatted with the fieldName, i.e

```
Property {0} must be a valid number
```

will be shown as

```
Property deviceTemperature must be a valid number
```

How can I change the field name to a readable string without changing the error message like:

`Property Device temperature must be a valid number`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a generated form GSP you will find the Grails convention. Example:

```
class Book {
  String title
}

<label for="title">
  <g:message code="book.title.label" default="Title" />
</label>
```

So you can always use `domainClassName.propertyName.label`.